# C#: Is it OK to hide implementation by inheritance?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Given that I have the following code:

```
interface IBase {
    void DoStuff(double x, double y);
}

class Base : IBase {
    public void DoStuff(double x, double y) { Console.WriteLine(x + y); }
}
```

Is it a good practice to override/hide the behavior of the base class without actually using the `override` keyword? Are there any hidden pitfalls in the code below?

```
class Derived : Base {
    public void DoStuff(double x, double y) { Console.WriteLine(x * y); }
}
```

Is it any better to use the `new` keyword here? Like so:

```
class Derived : Base {
    public new void DoStuff(double x, double y) { Console.WriteLine(x * y); }
}
```

Comment: `public void DoStuff` and `public new void DoStuff` have 0 differences in behavior except the first one throws a compiler warning and the 2nd does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to override/hide the behavior of the base class without actually using the override keyword?

You *can't* "override" the base method because it's not `virtual`.  All you *can* do is hide it.  It is very rarely a "good practice" but there's nothing that prevents it, so whether it's "good" or not is highly contextual.

> Is it any better to use the new keyword here?

Using `new` doesn't change the functionality in the slightest.  The keyword is there so that you can *explicitly* tell the compiler "I know that I'm hiding a base member".  The behavior will be the same whether you use `new` or not.

Comment: Would it be best if I changed the code to define the method as virtual in base? the problem here should there be a `class BaseB: IBase`, there is no way to enforce declaring the method as virtual.

Comment: You can make it `abstract` to force inheritors to provide their own implementation, but there's no way to "force" a class to make a method `virtual`

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I was looking for. Would you include this in your answer as well. Thanks.